# Java PrintWriter Flush in other thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an application that processes data and writes progress information to file using a PrintWriter. It is comparable to a logfile. What I perceive is that Java buffers almost all the output and thus the file is written at the end of the job. Hence I am thinking of regularly flushing the buffer.

Is it possible to setup a background thread that regularly runs PrintWriter.flush() or would I have to expect multithreading side effects if it collides with an ongoing PrintWriter.print() operation?

Comment: In the long run your best bet is probably to just take an existing logging framework. They've handled all of these problems before and are actively maintained.

Comment: So far I was hoping that PrintWriter is capable of this. If I have to care about synchronisation then a logging framework is definitely better.

Comment: For your specific question: Since [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html) don't mention thread safety anywhere, I'd say it's way safer to assume that it *doesn't* provide any guarantees.

Comment: Java buffers exactly 4096 `char`s of output. Not 'almost all'.

Comment: [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html) of `PrintWriter`: "Unlike the PrintStream class, if automatic flushing is enabled it will be done only when one of the println, printf, or format methods is invoked, rather than whenever a newline character happens to be output.". From the constructors that take a `boolean`: "autoFlush - A boolean; if true, the println, printf, or format methods will flush the output buffer" - no need for an additional Thread

Comment: I love that hint! So far I used new PrintWriter(File), and autoflush is not possible. So I need to run another constructor and see.

Comment: It worked, and the effort was minimal. Thanks again!